# Efficiency of memory allocation compared to loop iteration

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, utf-8

I have a function in C which takes a unicode codepoint as a wide character, and returns a pointer to an array of unsigned chars representing the UTF8 format of the wide character. I then have another function which takes a wide character and a pointer to an array, and inserts the wide character's UTF8 equivalent into the array (using the former function to convert the wide char to multi byte char).
My question is, as the latter function does not know the length of the returned UTF8 array (multi byte char), would it make more sense to have the former function return the length of the array instead, and assign an array to a predeclared unsigned char pointer passed as an argument?

```
char_u *wchar_to_mbchar(wchar_t *wChar)
{
    /* WARNING - NO NULL DELIM */

    char_u* mbChar;

    if(*wChar < 128) /* 1 byte chars */
    {
        mbChar = malloc(sizeof(char_u);

        *mbChar = *wChar; /* Is this okay?? */
    }
    else if(*wChar < 2048) /* 2 byte chars */
    {
        mbChar = malloc(2*sizeof(char_u));

        mbChar[0] = 192 + (*wChar >> 6);
        mbChar[1] = 128 + (*wChar - ((*wChar >> 6) << 6));
    }
    else if(*wChar < 65536) /* 3 byte chars */
    {
        mbChar = malloc(3*sizeof(char_u));

        mbChar[0] = 224 + (*wChar >> 12);
        mbChar[1] = 128 + ((*wChar - ((*wChar >> 12) << 12)) >> 6);
        mbChar[2] = 128 + (*wChar - ((*wChar >> 6) << 6));
    }
    else if(*wChar < 2097152) /* 4 byte chars */
    {
        mbChar = malloc(4*sizeof(char_u));

        mbChar[0] = 240 + (*wChar >> 18);
        mbChar[1] = 128 + ((*wChar - ((*wChar >> 18) << 18)) >> 12);
        mbChar[2] = 128 + ((*wChar - ((*wChar >> 12) << 12)) >> 6);
        mbChar[3] = 128 + (*wChar - ((*wChar >> 6) << 6));
    }
    return mbChar;
}

/* array, input wchar, char at */
int insert_mb_char(char_u* array,wchar_t* input,int insertAt) 
{
    char_u *mbChar;
    mbChar = wchar_to_mbchar(input);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < /*don't know how much to copy*/; i++)
        array[insertAt + i] = mbChar[i];

    return 0;
}
```

Or would it be better to insert null delimiters at the ends of the arrays returned by the first function, and simply iterate through them?
I suppose this would barely make a difference to code performance, but I just thought I'd ask.

Also, I know I shouldn't, but quick question - is it better to dereference a pointer and assign a value to the location it points to, or to assign the address of the new value to the pointer (assuming the new value already exists)?

Comment: I'm having trouble reading the question because my mind refuses to let go of the fact you're using `malloc` for each codepoint in a utf-8 string.  How slow!

Comment: Also, `mbChar` is uninitialized (for the error case)

Comment: Haha, sorry, this is the first time I've ever used C - what would you recommend?

Comment: It would make more sense to have the function return the length of the array instead, and assign the array to a predeclared unsigned char pointer passed as an argument.

Comment: Additionally, this code is only correct if `wchar_t` is 4 byte, or if it's 2 bytes and encoded as UCS-2 (which is almost never used anymore).  For Visual Studio and some other compilers, this code is only accurate for values less than 0xD7FF (55295 decimal), because they use UTF-16.

Comment: I was considering changing it to unsigned int (which I assume is 4 bytes on all platforms?)

Comment: `unsigned int` is 4 bytes on almost all desktop and laptop CPUs.  Best bet is to use `uint32_t`.

Comment: Okay, cheers. It'd be fairly easy to avoid all the malloc's by directly writing to whichever array the chars are going to end up in. I suppose that'd be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the reasons you have listed, and other reasons you haven't:  It would make more sense to have the function return the length of the array instead, and assign the array to a predeclared unsigned char pointer passed as an argument.

The primary reason here is that copying 1-4 bytes around is much much faster and less error prone than a single call to `malloc`.